# How to create a view for details of a single post and url in django?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website with a blog application in django 2.2. I only have a problem with the last step, which is to create a view for a single post. Unfortunately, I don't know how to finish it.

I created the simplest view I can, but after entering it, I get a 500 error from the server.

```py
 def single_post(request):
     return render(request=request, template_name="posts/single_post.html")
```

This is my model, view and url:

models.py

```
# Post models
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Tytuł")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Zawartość")
    lead = models.CharField(max_length=35, verbose_name="Skrót artykułu")
    published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Data publikacji", default=datetime.now())
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = "posts"

urlpatterns = [
    path("posts/", views.posts_list, name="posts_list"),
    path('<str:slug>/', views.single_post, name='single_post'),]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.

def posts_list(request):
    return render(request=request, template_name="posts/posts_list.html", context={"posts": Post.objects.all})

def single_post(request,slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request=request, template_name="posts/single_post.html", context={"post": post})
```

templates/posts/posts_list.html - is a page with all posts at exmaple.com/posts/

```
<section class="bg-light py-5" id="aktualnosci">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Informacje o zmianach w prawie podatkowym</h1>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <p class="text-paragraph pt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam iure consectetur accusantium delectus, iusto culpa mollitia eum molestiae at? Ab!</p>
    <div class="row py-3">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="news-card mb-3">
                <div class="text-center text-white bg-blue d-flex align-items-center news-card-date">
                    <div class="mx-auto news-card-date-body w-75">
                        <i class="far fa-calendar-alt d-none d-block mx-auto"></i>
                        <span class="d-block news-card-date-value mt-1">{{ post.published }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="news-card-body">
                    <div class="news-card-img">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'main/images/126.jpg' %}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="news-card-content">
                        <div class="news-card-content-inner">
                            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                            <p class="text-paragraph">{{ post.lead }}</p>
                            <a class="pb-2" href="{{ post.slug }}">Czytaj więcej</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like visitors to the site to be able to read the entire article. Currently, I was able to create only the entire page with all posts and their shortcuts.

Comment: what's the error trace? also have you actually gone through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views)? It shows you exactly what you need to do to write a view that renders one object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the post pk for this

```
def single_post(request,pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request=request, template_name="posts/single_post.html",{'post':post})
```

And in the template you can get the details like this

```
<p>{{post.title}}</p>
```

And also pass the pk as the url parameter for detail in your url

```
path('posts/<int:pk>',views.single_post,name='single_post')
```

You are not providing the correct url for the post detail url

```
<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
   <p class="text-paragraph">{{ post.lead }}</p>
   <a class="pb-2" href="{% url 'posts:single_post' post.slug %}">Czytaj więcej</a>
```

Comment: OK I understand. I made the above changes, but now I get a 404 error when clicking on the details of the post. And this is probably because in my model I defined the details of the post as SLUG, and this is not an intiger. Ultimately, friendly urls should be used in the blog.

Comment: @nsog8sm43x if you are passing slug instead of pk then you need to pass slug as the url parameter and in view get slug=slug instead of pk

Comment: @nsog8sm43x can you share what you have done with the updated question

Comment: of course, I substituted the values for the solution at the top.

Comment: @nsog8sm43x check my answer

Comment: I've tried to substitute str before, but it doesn't work either. All the time 404 error.

Comment: Did you provide the correct template ? Can you please update your question with the changes you have done with your dose @nsog8sm43x

Comment: When I remove posts/ from "path('posts/<str:slug>/', views.single_post, name='single_post')," urls.py, a single post works. But why doesn't the solution work at the top?

Comment: @nsog8sm43x please update your question with the làtest code

Comment: I have completed my code. But now a new problem has arisen. Individual posts work, e.g. example / new-post, but a url such as example.com/posts/new-post does not work.

Comment: @nsog8sm43x check my updated answer .You are not providing the correct url for the detail page

Answer (score 0):

Visit this page for more info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

```html
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView


class PostDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Post
```

Urls:

```html
from django.urls import path

from article.views import PostDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

example template page:

```html
<h1>{{ object.title}}</h1>
<p>{{ object.content }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you don't pass any context to your "single-post" template.

```
def single_post(request):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'post': post }

    return render(request, template_name="posts/single_post.html", context)
```

Then in your single_post.html template you can easily access any post model field.